# Will recursive Javascript Objects lead to any problems (memory leaks)?

Tags: javascript, json, performance

We pass our model entities via JSON through the API and inflate them later client-side so that we can use our objects in much the same way on client and server side. The entities have the standard Hibernate bi-directional relationships. When viewing an object in the console, as you dig deeper into the object you notice that because of those relationships, you can actually just keep expanding the properties further and further seemingly without end. For example:

```
$get.OrderItem {validations: Object, metaData: Object, $$getFormattedValue: function, data: Object, modifiedData: Object…}
```

The above Orderitem has an Order object in its data which in turn has an Orderitem object, and on and on. Does this have real world implications (are these things much bigger than they should be or are they memory leaks), or does the object representation in the console, simply keep expanding and has the representation of each entity separately? Is it simply an illusion caused by the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you are referring to the same object in memory each time it should be okay. I know AngularJS does this with the scope hierarchy: a child scope has a property equal to the parent scope, which has properties for the first and last child scopes and so on.

As long as you are not retaining a reference to those objects anywhere else in the code (i.e. not in this relationship graph object) so they cannot be cleaned up when you aren't using the whole tree any more, it should be okay.

You could always make sure you do explicit cleanup (nulling of properties) when an object is supposed to be "destroyed". I find that a helpful practice to help ward off memory leaks.